# What's the difference between AHK_Basic and AHK_L?

Tags: autohotkey

I've noticed that some AutoHotkey scripts specify that they were created specifically for either AHK_Basic or AHK_L.

From searching AHK questions on Stack Overflow, AHK_L seems to be the more popular variant, with [one question asking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15712415/3357935) how to enable AHK_L features in AHK_Basic.

- What's the difference between AHK_Basic and AHK_L?
- How can I tell which version I have?
- Which version is distributed on the [AutoHotkey website](https://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey

Comment: [I found an answer to my question on the AHK forums](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/96031-novice-question-ahk-basic-vs-ahk-l-whats-the-difference/?p=604799). (Posted as a comment to avoid taking credit for someone else's answer

Comment: AHK_Basic and AHK_L are not to be confused with [AHK_H](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=26497).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Any official version of AutoHotkey released within the past six years is based on AutoHotkey_L.

---

AutoHotkey Basic refers to AutoHotkey 1.0, while AutoHotkey_L refers to AutoHotkey 1.1

This is confirmed on the [AutoHotkey download page](https://autohotkey.com/download/):

> - AutoHotkey 1.1.* - previously known as **AutoHotkey_L**.
> - AutoHotkey 1.0.* - also retroactively known as **AutoHotkey Basic**, Classic, Vanilla, etc.
> - AutoHotkey 2.0-a* - see [AutoHotkey v2](https://autohotkey.com/v2/).
>
> <sub>**Source**: [AutoHotkey: Downloads](https://autohotkey.com/download/)</sub>

AutoHotkey_L was originally a fork of Autohotkey created by [Lexicos](https://github.com/Lexikos). To distinguish between the original AHK and Lexicos's fork, users began referring to them as *AHK_Basic* and *AHK_L* respectively.

> AHK_L was at one time a very popular fork of AHK, and when AHK's
>   creator began to lose interest in maintaining the official branch many
>   people called for AHK_L to be designated as the official branch of the
>   program.
>
> **It took some years to decide to make AHK_L the official
>   branch, so in the meantime users here coined the terms "AHK Basic" and
>   "AHK_L" to help users distinguish between the different versions. But
>   since AHK_L is now the official branch, it is AHK and there's no need
>   to distinguish.**
>
> <sub>**Source**: [Post by sinkface](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/96031-novice-question-ahk-basic-vs-ahk-l-whats-the-difference/?p=604799) on [*AHK_Basic vs. AHK_L, what's the difference?*](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/96031-novice-question-ahk-basic-vs-ahk-l-whats-the-difference/)</sub>

AutoHotkey_L was made the official branch of AutoHotkey in 2012. The source code can be found at https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L

If you're curious, the source code for AutoHotkey Basic (1.0.x) [is publicly available on GitHub](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey). The last non-readme update for AHK Basic was made on September 25, 2009. ([v1.0.48.05](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/commit/db43da8f2c7d44634ebea87748bcec6b120c34c7)).